# Change array order (like columns)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to change the order from:

```
$array = array(
    "a" => "bar",
    "b" => "foo",
    "c" => "bar",
    "d" => "foo",
    "e" => "bar",
    "f" => "foo",
    "g" => "bar",
    "h" => "foo",
    "i" => "bar",
    "j" => "foo"
);
```

To:

```
$array = array(
    "a" => "bar",   "f"=> "foo",
    "b" => "foo",   "g"=> "bar",
    "c" => "bar",   "h"=> "foo",
    "d" => "foo",   "i"=> "bar",
    "e" => "bar",   "j"=> "foo"
);
```

The point of this is that I want to fill a table with the items in the array:

The array should not be sorted like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 3</td><td>Item 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

But like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Item 1</td><td>Item 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Item 2</td><td>Item 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to display the results on a web-page, you need to look into `css` as that would be more suitable for the job.

Comment: CSS and HTML will be needed to have an output of columns. Please specific more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to rearrange the original array. Just split it up in two pairs using array_chunk, and loop through them when building the html.

```
$array = array(....);
$size = ceil(count($array) / 2);
list($left, $right) = array_chunk($array, $size, true);
echo '<table>';
while (count($left) > 0) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', key($left), ': ', array_shift($left), '</td>';
    echo '<td>', key($right), ': ', array_shift($right), '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Oh hey, I had not thought of that yet. I think this is the easiest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it does not mater whether the key is an string or a integer.

```
$array = array(
    4 => 'd',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
    6 => 'f',
    5 => 'e',
    1 => 'a'
);

$x = floor(count( $array ) / 2);
for( $i=1; $i <= $x; $i++ )
{
    $array2[ $i ] = $array[ $i ];
    $array2[ $i + $x ] = $array[ $i + $x ];
}
```

will output:

```
$Array2
(
    [1] => a, [4] => d,
    [2] => b, [5] => e,
    [3] => c, [6] => f
)
```

JB